# Помогите с выравниваем кнопок(Android Studio)

Tags: android, xml

возникла проблема, не знаю как выровнять 10 кнопок так, чтобы они были распределены равномерно вдоль экрана.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_server"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="20dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@drawable/food_bg">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
    android:text="Add this check"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnBackToWork"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnBackToWork"
    android:text="Back to Work"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="200px"
    android:layout_height="200px"
    android:src="@drawable/espresso"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"/>
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="200px"
    android:layout_height="200px"
    android:src="@drawable/americano"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"/>
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_width="200px"
    android:layout_height="200px"
    android:src="@drawable/capuchino"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"/>
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:layout_width="200px"
    android:layout_height="200px"
    android:src="@drawable/latte"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"/>
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
    android:layout_width="200px"
    android:layout_height="200px"
    android:src="@drawable/hot_water"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"/>
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
    android:layout_width="200px"
    android:layout_height="200px"
    android:src="@drawable/double_espresso"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"/>
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
    android:layout_width="200px"
    android:layout_height="200px"
    android:src="@drawable/cofe_with_milk"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton6"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"/>
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton8"
    android:layout_width="200px"
    android:layout_height="200px"
    android:src="@drawable/vanilniy_kapuchino"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton7"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"/>
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton9"
    android:layout_width="200px"
    android:layout_height="200px"
    android:src="@drawable/mokachino"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton8"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"/>
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton10"
    android:layout_width="200px"
    android:layout_height="200px"
    android:src="@drawable/hot_choko"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton5"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton9"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"/>
```

Comment: Здравствуйте. Что вы имеете ввиду под "равномерно вдоль экрана"? Они центрированы должны быть по левому краю, по размеру, по правому краю. Лучше пример добавить.

Comment: Как вариант LinearLayout с android:layout_weight

Comment: Я согласен с распространенным мнением, что ситуаций, когда стоит использовать RelativeLayout придумать сложно. Используйте вместо него ConatraintLayout. Оно использует похожий принцип, но дает куда большие возможности и, вроде как, быстрее работает. 

А по-поводу приведенной разметки - если не считать пары излишних атрибутов он должен работать. По крайней мере редактор в студии отображает макет как надо. Опишите что именно выглядит/работает не так как должно

Comment: @СпицкоДмитрий, хорошо попробую, пока сделал на релятиве, но интересно попробовать более удобные способы)

Comment: Так а что за проблема? Как я говорил выше, моя студия скушала вашу разметку и не подавилась) Кнопки сверху в 2 ряда, две снизу друг под другом